# <service-name> dead but pid file exists

Tags: linux, tomcat, service, cassandra

A service has crashed on my server and when I do

```
service <service-name> status
```

I get  dead but pid file exists, then if I try to stop the service I get

```
Shutdown <service-name>: bash: line 0: kill: (5018) - No such process
ERROR: could not stop <service-name>:  <service-name> dead but pid file exists
```

Then I delete the files in /var/run//.pid and var/lock/subsys/ but it does not help.
What should I do in order to really restart the service?

Comment: This isn't a programming question. superuser.com or serverfault.com would be more appropriate, please request migration.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

have you tried :

```
kill -9 pid
ps -eaf|grep pid
```

If pid gone now, try :
`service service-name restart`
(stop will fail, but should success when starting)

Comment: kill- 9 fails because the pid in  /var/run/.pid does not actually exist

Comment: the service is cassandra

Comment: found below:http://mysmallworldonbigdata.blogspot.com.au/2013/06/installing-cassandra-in-cent-os.html

Comment: From above link:"cassandra dead but pid file exists". To fix this issue, Edit the cassandra-env.sh:
sudo vi /etc/cassandra/conf/cassandra-env.sh
and change the 180k to 256k like this:
JVM_OPTS="$JVM_OPTS -Xss180k"
to:
JVM_OPTS="$JVM_OPTS -Xss256k"

Comment: https://baioradba.wordpress.com/2014/06/13/how-to-install-cassandra-on-centos-6-5/

Answer (score -1):

Kafka rest process dead but pid file exists solutions
Please do the followings:
Navigate the .bash_profile folder and open it with vi .bash_profile and edit java version in the .bash_profile
##export {old version} (comment this old java version)
export {new version}

then save the file with :wq! and come out of the Linux box
And start again and this time kafka rest process dead but pid file exists won't display

Answer (score -6):

just do

```
service [service_name] stop
service [service_name] restart
```

Comment: Hey khalrd this will not work if the vm thinks the process is working